# Сортировка по словарю на PHP

Tags: php, массивы, сортировка

Потребовалось отсортировать массив по словарю(элементы вне словаря должны идти после отсортированных), воспользовался вот этим вариантом https://stackoverflow.com/a/22094707/5326802. Сортировка работает, но элементы вне словаря идут в топ списка, хотя должны уходить вниз. 
В чём ошибка данного способа? И есть ли другие варианты решения проблемы?

Использовался вот этот вариант -

```
$weights = array_flip(array('112','111','132','100'));
usort($data, function($x, $y) use($weights) {
if (!isset($weights[$x['id']], $weights[$y['id']])) {
    // none of the ids have weight, so sort by bare id
    return $x['id'] - $y['id'];
}
else if (!isset($weights[$x['id']])) { 
    // x does not have weight, put it last
    return 1;
}
else if (!isset($weights[$y['id']])) {
    // y does not have weight, put it last
    return -1;
}

// both have weights, use them
return $weights[$x['id']] - $weights[$y['id']];   });
```

Comment: По ссылке три разных варианта. Какой из них вы используете? Покажите свой код лучше.

Comment: @АлексейУколов третий вариант, который помечен как ответ

Comment: Пробовали менять местами `1` и `-1`?

Comment: @Arnial , да, ничего не происходит.